# virtualenv directories are not showing up on webfaction

Tags: django, virtualenv, webfaction

I have installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on webfaction for deploying a django application and its working fine. Im able to create virtual environments and also tested django app and it is working fine but the directories of virtual environments are not showing up! Virtual environments are getting created and activated but, their directories are not there!

This is my `bashrc` and I have configured it to make virtual environments in a folder called virutalenvs. This folder is empty even after creating environments. What is happening?

Thank you.

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi


# User specific aliases and functions

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /home/hammad/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
```

Comment: have you tried to use virtualenv directly, that is without a wrapper?

Comment: its working without the wrapper! is this is a known issue? how do i solve it?

Comment: why bother with the wrapper then?